# function something(tag value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question that I have been trying to figure out, but the problem is, I don't know what I am being asked to do so I don't even know where to start with the question. I am very uneducated in coding and have no clue at all what my first step would be and how I would go about the problem. The question gives me HTML code and asks me the following:

> Write a function replace(tag, value) that takes two strings as argument. The first is a tag (e.g, "item" (without quotes) and the second is a replacement value (e.g., "flux capacitor" (without quotes). This function should replace the innerHTML of the element with the given tag with the specified value.
>
> If the tag does not exist your function should display an alert to indicate that the tag was not found. Test your code by defining the format() function which is tied to the Format button by replacing 'salutation' with 'Mr. Smith', 'invoice' with 123, 'item' with 'flux capacitor' and 'threaten' with 'Please do not make me angry'.

What is this question asking me to do? to me it sounds like gibberish (although I am sure it is not) and I have searched the web but still I haven't come across anything helpful.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="q1.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</head>
<body>
Dear <span id="salutation">Name</span>;
<p>
It has come to our attention that your invoice <span id="invoice">ID</span>
has yet to be paid. It has now been <span id="time">some time</span> since
you received <span id="item">the material</span> from Evil Incorporated.         Please
remit payment immediately. <span id="threaten"></span>
</p>
Yours sincerely,<br>
<br>
<br>
J. Smith, Accounting
<div id="buttons">
<center>
<button onclick="format()">Format</button>
<button onclick="clearit()">Clear</button>
</center>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take the JS course here - https://www.codecademy.com/

Comment: PLZ PROVIDE CODE ALSO

Comment: @darshan dave here is the html code (in the edit)

Comment: @darshandave here is the html code (in the edit)

Comment: @Cory This looks cool, is it free to use? like a lesson by lesson kinda thing? if so then this will be very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Yes, free. starts at the very basics. You will be writing functions in about one hour

Comment: Thank you very much for the link Cory!

Comment: The task given already sounds like a homework. And if it is a homework and you don't even understand it, you are in a hell of a problem. Not so much because you will likely fail this homework (unless somebody will provide you with the code), but because you obviously missed a lot if not all of the foundations built by the course so far or you did not match the requirements. You should address this problem asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for..:D

```js
function format(){
 Replace('salutation','Mr. Smith');
 Replace('invoice','123');
 Replace('item','flux capacitor');
 Replace('threaten','Please dont make me angry');
}
function clearit(){
    Replace('salutation','Name');
 Replace('invoice','ID');
 Replace('item','the material');
 Replace('threaten','');
}
function Replace(tag,value){
 if($('body').find('#'+tag)){
  $('#'+tag).html(value);
 }
    else{alert('Tag not found');}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script src="q1.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</head>
<body>
Dear <span id="salutation">Name</span>;
<p>
It has come to our attention that your invoice <span id="invoice">ID</span>
has yet to be paid. It has now been <span id="time">some time</span> since
you received <span id="item">the material</span> from Evil Incorporated.         Please
remit payment immediately. <span id="threaten"></span>
</p>
Yours sincerely,<br>
<br>
<br>
J. Smith, Accounting
<div id="buttons">
<center>
<button onclick="format();">Format</button>
<button onclick="clearit();">Clear</button>
</center>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks very complicated, if this is what i am to do then i have alot to search up and read on. thank you very much! I will analyse this code snippet and find out how it works, may I ask questions about this code here if need be?

Comment: oh, sure you can ask about it here..:)

Comment: @KingLynx: I do not recommend that you submit this as homework without understanding it. I believe in the academic world, this is technically known as "cheating". Adarsh - there is no specific edict here to avoid doing student's homework for them, but it may be more helpful in the future to do less of it `:-)`.

Comment: haha. i dint think about that..:D

Comment: @halfer Oh no, this isnt homework it is a practice before the real lab, generally the practices have similar aspects as the practice but they change it up. like the base is the same which means If I can learn what I am to do here it will help me understand what may be on the test. So yes I  dont plan to submit it I plan to study how this works and why.

Comment: @AdarshMohan, Thank you very much for the helpful post XD I mean I wanted someone to tell me what tools I would need so i could figure it out myself, but I guess looking at a certain code will also have the same learning effect I guess. In any case thank you for the generous help!

Comment: You are always welcome..:D

Comment: OK, fair enough Adarsh - if you can learn from this, that's great. Don't forget though that writing code is what will create the greatest learning opportunity.